# Grayscale canvas based on percentage (In FireFox)

Tags: css, firefox, canvas, css-filters

I'm having some trouble trying to get Grayscale working with Firefox. I'd love to be able to this:

```
$(element).css('filter', 'grayscale(' + val + '%)');
```

But I know that's not going to happen

Now I'm aware I can do some fancy stuff with SVG-based filters, but I need to be able to control the percentage of the grayscale filter fluidly. To be specific, I'm going to have the background of my page become more saturated as you scroll farther down.

Now that would normally be simple, since I could just embed an SVG or overlay a grayscale copy of my image on top, but I'm acually using a <canvas> as the background. Now from there I could just apply a custom filter to the canvas, but its being updated multiple times per second using [rainyday.js](http://maroslaw.github.io/rainyday.js/).

Currently, the closest I've come is this:

```
$(element).css('filter', 'url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'' + (100 - val) + '\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale")');
```

But that code makes it so my canvas consistently refreshes while scrolling, making it so I can't even see my background.

So how on earth can I get Grayscale to work with Firefox? I'm open to anything, no matter how hacky it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you applying it on a `<canvas>`? Just use a container with background image and apply rainyday.js on the canvas inside it.

In that way you wouldn't care about the canvas updating anymore.

#### EDIT

Maybe this is the case where you have to go full way with js. On [this link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grayscale-image-web/) you can find a simple js way to grayscale images with js(2nd point).

I'd suggest you to save that output into a variable and place it as src in the rainyday.js `run()` function.

Something like

```
var imgObj = document.getElementById('background');

function gray(imgObj) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var imgW = imgObj.width;
    var imgH = imgObj.height;
    canvas.width = imgW;
    canvas.height = imgH;

    canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
    var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

    for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
imgObj.src = gray(imgObj);


function run() {
    var image = document.getElementById('background');
    image.onload = function() {
        var engine = new RainyDay({
            image: this
        });
        engine.rain([ [1, 2, 8000] ]);
        engine.rain([ [3, 3, 0.88], [5, 5, 0.9], [6, 2, 1] ], 100);
    };
    image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    image.src = gray(imgObj);
}
```

Just supposing, I have not tested it.

Comment: And how would I go about making that container grayscale?

Comment: Ok, as if I said nothing...it doesn't work because rainyday.js overcome anything under it.